# How to insert data from one table to other table with some static data in single statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've one table Car as below

```
Car_ID | Car_Name
```

**Sample data**

```
Car_ID    Car_Name
1         Honda City
2         Ferrari
3         Mercedes
4         Rolls Royce
```

I've data in Car table. Now i've other table Car_Detail as below

```
Car_Detail_ID | Car_ID | Car_Color
```

Now i've to insert data into Car_Detail from Car where Car_Color will be default value. How to achieve this in single statement ?

**Expected result**

```
Car_Detail_ID   Car_ID    Color
1               1         Red
2               2         Red
3               3         Red
4               4         Red
```

## **EDIT**

**Sample Data**

**Car Table**

```
Car_ID    Car_Name
1         Honda City
2         Ferrari
3         Mercedes
4         Rolls Royce
```

**Color Table**

```
Color_ID    Color_Name
1           Red
2           Yellow
3           Blue
4           Green
```

**Expected Result**

```
Car_Detail_ID   Car_ID    Color_ID
1               1         1
2               2         1
3               3         1
4               4         1
5               1         2
6               2         2
7               3         2
8               4         2
9               1         3
10              2         3
11              3         3
12              4         3
13              1         4
14              2         4
15              3         4
16              4         4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement, the query below assumes that `Car_Detail_ID` is an auto-incremented column and `Color` has a default value of `Red`

```
INSERT INTO Car_Detail (Car_ID)
SELECT Car_ID
FROM Car
```

but if not,

```
INSERT INTO Car_Detail (Car_ID, Color)
SELECT Car_ID, 'Red' Color
FROM Car
```

or something like this,

```
INSERT INTO Car_Detail (Car_Detail_ID, Car_ID, Color)
SELECT Car_ID, Car_ID, 'Red' Color
FROM Car
```

**UPDATE 1**

use `CROSS JOIN`

```
INSERT INTO CAr_Detail(Car_ID, Color_ID)
SELECT  Car_ID, Color_ID
FROM Car CROSS JOIN Color
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbc1af/1)

Comment: If we've to add from two table than? Though above code is working fine.

Comment: the source of records are from two table or the destination of the records is to the two tables?

Comment: suppose car_detail contains tow FK

Comment: you can using `UNION` in your select or `JOIN`, can you show smple data?

Comment: Ok, I m updating data in question

Comment: Updated data into question, please find in EDIT portion.

Comment: Can u please help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697368/updating-inserted-record-within-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008-r2 this question?